# How do I determine the WCF namespace from a PropertyInfo?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, xsd

I'm writing an implementation of `IWsdlExportExtension` and I've collected a list of `PropertyInfo` instances that need their corresponding XSD declarations to be modified. In order to do this, I need to determine their XML namespace.

I understand that looking at the `DataMemberAttribute` is not enough. Is there a built in method in the WCF libraries that can provide that information? Otherwise, would the algorithm look like to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is get an instance of the [ContractDescription class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.contractdescription.aspx). This class has a [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.contractdescription.namespace.aspx) property.

You can get an instance of this class using one of the [GetContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms556218.aspx) methods. They have a Type parameter. So In your case, you could use this kind of call:

```
string myNamespace = ContractDescription.GetContract(
          typeof(IMyService),
          myPropertyInfo.DeclaringType).Namespace;
```

NOTE: you will also need the contract type (represented in this sample by `typeof(IMyService)`)